# Mocking an Object's method calls by EasyMock after injecting it using PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, powermock, easymock

I have a following class in my project for which I am trying to write a test case

```
Class A{
    a(){
        B b = new B();
        int ans = b.somefunction();
    }
}
```

I need to mock somefunction() call in above class for my test

I tried following to achieve this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class,B.class})
Class TestA{
    testa(){
        EasyMock mb = EasyMock.createMock(B.class);
        PowerMock.createMock(B.class);
        PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(mb);
        EasyMock.expect(mb.somefunction()).andReturn(0);
        EasyMock.replay(mb);
        PowerMock.replay(B.class);
    }
}
```

but it always gives Java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call B.somefunction()

I have PowerMock 1.5.5 and EasyMock 3.2 in my package

Can someone help me with the above problem and help me figure out where exactly I am going wrong. I am new to using EasyMock and PowerMock.

Does there exist a simpler way to test given class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing test case properly,the constructor in test class is not needed

the correct way would be to do it like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class,B.class})
class TestA{
    B mb=EasyMock.createNiceMock(B.class); 
    PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(mb).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(mb.somefunction()).andReturn(0).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.replay(mb);
    PowerMock.replayAll();

    A a=new A(); //calling A's Constructor so that test case actually runs
}
```

hope this helps!

Good luck